# Python Mechanize change unnamed input value (known id)

Tags: python, html, forms, mechanize

as is written in topic i have to change value of some input field using mechanize but i dont have name of it only id :/ Let's stick to the point.

This is how form looks:

```
<form id="Login" name="Login">

    <div id="login-inputs-div">
        <input id="Username" type="hidden" name="username"></input>
        <input id="Password" type="hidden" name="password"></input>
        <input id="PopupUsername" class="input-text input-text-gray" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="admin" maxlength="32" style="width:100px;"></input>
        <input id="PopupPassword" class="input-text input-text-gray " type="password" maxlength="32" value="" style="width:100px;" placeholder="hasło"></input>
        <input id="bt_authenticate" class="input-btn input-btn-orange translation Translations.general.btn.authenticate translated" type="submit" value="zaloguj"></input>
    </div>
    <div id="logout-link-div" style="display: none;"></div>

</form>
```

What i have to do? Fill PopupPassword using some value and later submit it?

My approach looks like:

```
import mechanize

url = "http://192.168.1.1"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open(url)

br.select_form(name="Login")
br.form().find_control(id="PopupPassword").__setattr__("value", "something")
res = br.submit()
content = res.read()
```

Im looking forward for some solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `find_control()` is exactly what needs to be done here. What is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Well somehow it returns AttributeError: HTMLForm instance has no __call__ method and i have no idea how to change attribute :s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find_control()` is exactly what you need here. Just don't call `br.form`, it is not a function:

```
password_field = br.form.find_control(id="PopupPassword")
password_field.value = "something"
```

Comment: Eh, somehow that Livebox config webpage is kinda retarded, or im sleepy, but i cannot log in into it, still thanks.

Comment: @windoo might be something else. Consider creating a separate question with details. Thanks.